# Python: New Object instance on every call of function

Tags: python, django, api, celery

I'm trying to update a base class with a session token and user id for long polling.

Every time I call my function I create a new instance which calls a login function, that I don't want to happen.

I only want to call the `login()` method when the value is `None`

How do I return the instance of apiclient after the session token is set to use with the function for `get_balance`??

**client.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import requests
import os
from matchbook import endpoints
class BaseClient(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password=None, locale=None):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.locale = locale
        self.url_beta = 'https://beta.matchbook.com'
        self.urn_main = '/bpapi/rest/'
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session_token = None
        self.user_id = None  

    def set_session_token(self, session_token, user_id):

        self.session_token = session_token
        self.user_id = user_id

class APIClient(BaseClient):

    def __init__(self, username, password=None):
        super(APIClient, self).__init__(username, password)
        self.login = endpoints.Login(self)
        self.account = endpoints.Account(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<APIClient [%s]>' % self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return 'APIClient'
```

**get_bal.py**

```
from client import APIClient
from celery import shared_task
def get_client():

    apiclient = APIClient(username, password)
    if apiclient.session_token is None:

        apiclient.login()

        session_token = apiclient.session_token
        user_id = apiclient.user_id
        apiclient.set_session_token(session_token,user_id)

    else:
        print('session token assigned',apiclient.session_token, apiclient.user_id)
    return apiclient

@shared_task
def get_balance():
    apiclient = get_client() *to call instance after login is set*
    r = apiclient.account.get_account()
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `APIClient` each time you call `get_client()`, which is what happens each time `get_balance()` get called.

You need to maintain an instance of the `APIClient` outside of the function scope for you to carry over your program and update your `get_balance()` to not call `get_client()` each time:

```
def get_balance(apiclient):
    r = apiclient.account.get_account()
    print(r)

def main():
    apiclient = get_client()
    get_balance(apiclient)  # pass instance of APIClient in as an argument
```

Another note in your `get_client()` function, since both of the `if` conditions are the opposite of each other, just wrap them in an `if... else` block:

```
def get_client():

    apiclient = APIClient(username, password)

    if apiclient.session_token is None:

        apiclient.login()

        session_token = apiclient.session_token
        user_id = apiclient.user_id
        apiclient.set_session_token(session_token,user_id)

    else:
        print('session token assigned',apiclient.session_token, apiclient.user_id)

    return apiclient
```

---

All that said, a much more OOP way would be to bake the `get_balance()` into the `APIClient` as an instance method so you don't even need to worry about the instance:

```
class APIClient(BaseClient):

    ...

    def get_balance(self):
        print(self.account.get_account())

# Then just call the get_balance() anywhere:

apiclient = get_client()
apiclient.get_balance()
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer on the if else block. I am planning to poll my `get_balance` function with a celery task. Should I place a shared_task decorator over the main function or get_balance function in order to poll `get_balance` or would this be outside of scope?

Comment: I am honestly not familiar with `celery` further than it being a task queue, so I wouldn't be able to comment on that part.  However I'd imagine if you put it in as an instance method, the method being tied to the instance should ensure the method is called for the same instance.

Comment: How do I call just get_balance(apiclient) on it's own without wrapping it in a main method with get_client()? It that possible?

Comment: If you need to maintain the session then you need *something* to keep it outside of the scope of `get_balance()`.  Hence why I suggested use it as an instance method, then it's easily portable to call `apiclient.get_balance()` whenever you have already created the instance.